# What does [:-1] mean/do in python?

Tags: python

Working on a python assignment and was curious as to what [:-1] means in the context of the following code: `instructions = f.readline()[:-1]`

Have searched on here on S.O. and on Google but to no avail. Would love an explanation!

Comment: Sometimes -1 is used to express the end of an array of things.  My guess is this means to read from beginning to the end of the line (but just a guess, hence not an official answer).

Comment: I'm not sure it's a dup, because of that "in the context of…" part—which is the part that you and, especially, Pavel Anossov answered.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

It slices the string to omit the last character, in this case a newline character:

```
>>> 'test\n'[:-1]
'test'
```

Since this works even on empty strings, it's a pretty safe way of removing that last character, if present:

```
>>> ''[:-1]
''
```

This works on any sequence, not just strings.

For lines in a text file, I’d actually use `line.rstrip('\n')` to *only remove a newline*; sometimes the last line in the file doesn’t end in a newline character and using slicing then removes whatever other character is last on that line.

Answer (score 16):

It means "all elements of the sequence but the last". In the context of `f.readline()[:-1]` it means "I'm pretty sure that line ends with a newline and I want to strip it".

Comment: Although Martijn Pieters's answer is a bit more detailed and explanatory, I like that this one directly describes the idiom of using `[:-1]` with `readline`, answering the OP's "in the context of…" part. (So, +1 to both of you.)

Comment: It might be worth noting that making this assumption can be a dangerous thing to do, even on a system where you expect the end-of-line marker to be one character long-- it's not uncommon to wind up with a missing newline on the last line of a file.  This is particularly true when Python is involved: I've seen `'\n'.join(lines)` used before, which will result in exactly this happening, and then you lose a data character..

Answer (score 15):

It selects all but the last element of a sequence.

Example below using a list:

```
In [15]: a=range(10)

In [16]: a
Out[16]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

In [17]: a[:-1]
Out[17]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: It slices the *sequence* - it just might happen to be a list.

Answer (score 3):

It gets all the elements from the list (or characters from a string) but the last element.

`:` represents going through the list
`-1` implies the last element of the list

Comment: This is written ambiguously enough to be confusing. It's all of the elements up to _but not including_ the last element. (If you already know how slices/ranges/etc. work in Python, then knowing that -1 is the last element tells you everything you need… but if you don't, you still won't after this answer.)